# Result not as expected while generating URLs for routes with multiple parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes, request

The result of request is shown vice versa in the controller while using URL generation,

**My route:**

```
Route::get('district/{district}/municipal/{slug}', 'UIController@municipaldetail')->name('web-municipal_detail.show');
```

**Blade:**

```
<a href="{{route('web-municipal_detail.show',['slug' => 1,'district'=>2] )}}" class="btn btn-primary">++ More Details ++</a>
```

**Chrome generated URL on hover()**

```
localhost/district/1/municipal/2
```

**Controller**

```
public function municipaldetail($slug, $district){
  dd($slug); // shows me the result of "2" and 
  dd($district); // shows me the result "1"
}
```

but when I reverse the order of the request  it works fine

```
public function municipaldetail($district,$slug ){
  dd($slug); // 1 
  dd($district); // 2
}
```

I am confused why this happen, Please explain to me how the controller handles the request attributes and please do let me know if you need further details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route parameters are being passed to your method as arguments in order, in this case.

```
Route::get('test/{a}/{b}', function ($a, $b) {
    dd(compact('a', 'b'));
});
```

Hit that route: `yoursite.test/test/a/b`

```
array:2 [▼
  "a" => "a"
  "b" => "b"
]
```

Then change the order of the Closure parameters:

```
Route::get('test/{a}/{b}', function ($b, $a) {
    dd(compact('a', 'b'));
});
```

Then hit the route again:

```
array:2 [▼
  "a" => "b"
  "b" => "a"
]
```

They are passed in the same order they are defined in the route.